# Comparing two NSDates date and time ignoring seconds

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to compare two dates and time by ignoring the seconds. Below is the code which I have tried but seems to be unsuccessful. Can anyone help me where I am going wrong or provide me with a better solution? Thanks

```
-(BOOL)checkIfTimePassed{

    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

    BOOL isTimePassed = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] compareDate:today toDate:self.whenDate toUnitGranularity:NSCalendarUnitMinute] != NSOrderedAscending;

    return isTimePassed;
}
```

Comment: This code should be working. Could you please show us two dates they you are trying to compare?

Comment: Suppose today = [NSDate date] & self.whenDate = [NSDate date] but some seconds ago and minute is same, it says time is passed

Comment: Note how such comparing works, if you are comparing e.g. `10:01:50` with `10:01:55` ignoring the seconds, you are essentially comparing `10:01` and `10:01`. You have to be very careful about the condition because times close to each other will be `NSOrderedSame`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be working solution as of now. If anyone gets better one do post it.

```
-(BOOL)checkIfTimePassed{

    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

    NSComparisonResult result = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] compareDate:today toDate:self.whenDate toUnitGranularity:NSCalendarUnitMinute];

    if(result==NSOrderedAscending){
        NSLog(@"today is less");
        return NO;
    }
    else if(result==NSOrderedDescending)
    {
        NSLog(@"newDate is less");
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Both dates are same");
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: I checked, and it returns exactly the same result as my solution. Please tell me why my solution is not correct.

Comment: It returns `NO`, as does yours. As you can see my code compares `== NSOrderedAscending`, so it must return `NO` when the return value is `NSOrderedSame`.

Answer (score 4):

Your comparing is off. Try this instead. Note the change in parameters and comparing.

```
-(BOOL)checkIfTimePassed{

    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

    BOOL isTimePassed = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] compareDate:self.whenDate toDate:today toUnitGranularity:NSCalendarUnitMinute] == NSOrderedAscending;

    return isTimePassed;
}
```

Comment: Not working. It gives NO even if the time has passed.

Comment: I just tried it with a bit more than one minute difference, and it returned YES.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];
NSDate *endDate = [startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:+7*24*60*60];

NSDateFormatter *df=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];


    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"];



- (BOOL)validateDates:(NSDate*)startDate EndDate:(NSDate*)endDate{
    NSComparisonResult dateCompareResutFinal = [startDate compare:endDate];

    if (dateCompareResutFinal == NSOrderedDescending) {
        [RKDropdownAlert dismissAllAlert];
        [RKDropdownAlert title:AlertNotificationError message:@"Start date should be less than End date" backgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0 green:0.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:0.7] textColor:[UIColor whiteColor] time:2 delegate:self]
        ;
        return NO;
    }else if (dateCompareResutFinal == NSOrderedSame) {
        [RKDropdownAlert dismissAllAlert];
        [RKDropdownAlert title:AlertNotificationError message:@"Both dates cannot be same" backgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0 green:0.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:0.7] textColor:[UIColor whiteColor] time:2 delegate:self];

        return NO;
    }else{
        return YES;
    }
}
```